# Hooking Int 09h interrupt

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16

I have a problem hooking int 09h I've changed the pointer to my new Isr, if I debug on windows, the interrupt is triggered every time I push a key. But in VMWare it seems that only is triggered one time and no more. I've tested in DOS 6.22 and happens exactly the same.

My code look like this:

```
MyIsr:
    pusha
    pushf
    ;tell PIC that interrupt has finished
    mov al,0x20
    out 0x20,al
    popf
    popa
    iret
```

---

If I use a USB keyboard can I send the same commands like Ps/2?

Comment: Try to save the previous ISR pointer from the IVT before you overwrite it and call it from your ISR instead of ACK:ing the IRQ.  Remember to PUSHF before CALL:ing the old pointer (to simulate the int-call)

Comment: If I use a USB keyboard can I send the same commands like Ps/2?

Comment: If you don't read a key from the keyboard (input from port 0x60) when a keyboard interrupt occurs, you will receive no further interrupts from the keyboard. In the code you show you don't do any read from the keyboard port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of issues here, as you haven't posted a complete view of the code you are writing. Could you please explain exactly what you are tying to accomplish?

If an ISR is called and not handled, you won't be able to do anything, so keep this in mind. Your problem may be related to how you are installing the ISR in the interrupt vector table.

- In real mode, you do it with INT 21h, AH=25h
- In protected mode, under DJGPP, you need to use a DPMI function (either using INT 21H functions, or using C functions. See [DPMI documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_199.html)
- Locking down the memory for the ISR is also needed when running in PM, as the memory can get "paged out" (You need this for the ISR because we don't really "know" when it will run).

Regardless, your ISR should look more like the following:

```
newInt9:

enter 0,0
push eax

in al, 60h
mov [raw_key], al

mov al, 20h
out 20h, al

pop eax
leave
iret
```

;endproc

Comment: Well, Im trying to get the pressed key I'm working in real mode MS-DOS 6.22 another thing it's that I'm using USB Keyboard with legacy supported enabled.

And in my original function I' dont make enter and leave for stack frame. I'll test agian with PS/2 keyboard and I'll tell you the results